# C# Facing issue to encrypt and decrypt text by Base64

Tags: c#, base64

I encrypt the text **ZIRT** to Base64 this way:

```
public static string encrypt(string ToEncrypt)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ToEncrypt));
}
```

after encrypt the text becomes **V2tsU1ZB** and when I try to decrypt using the below function:

```
public static string decrypt(string cypherString)
{
    //return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(cypherString));

    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(cypherString);
    string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    return decodedString;
}
```

then I am getting this text **WklSVA** but it is supposed to be **ZIRT**.

What is wrong in my code?

I am giving more code which fails to decrypt the text:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strTxt = "ZIRT";

    string ss = EnryptString(strTxt);

    string ss1 = EnryptString(ss);
}

public string DecryptString(string encrString)
{
    byte[] b;
    string decrypted;
    try
    {
        b = Convert.FromBase64String(encrString);
        decrypted = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
    }
    catch (FormatException fe)
    {
        decrypted = "";
    }
    return decrypted;
}

public string EnryptString(string strEncrypted)
{
    byte[] b = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strEncrypted);
    string encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
    return encrypted;
}
```

Comment: Just as info for you Base64 does not encypt anything. It just encodes the text in another way.

Comment: encrypt("ZIRT") gives "WklSVA==" for me, not "V2tsU1ZB". and decrypt("WklSVA==") gives "ZIRT" back.

Comment: and decoding `V2tsU1ZB` gives `WklSVA`. Did you encode twice? From  ZIRT->WklSVA->V2tsU1ZB

Comment: From your code it looks like you're encoding twice instead of encoding & decoding.

Comment: You are encrypting with ASCII and then decrypting with UTF8.  To debug encryption the encryption and decryption steps are symmetrical.  I always start by check the send (encrypted) data matches received (encrypted) data.  First do a byte count check.  Then go back one step and verify on send side the before Encoding matches receive side after decoding.  Looks like your send and receive are both use Encoding when receive side should use Decoding.

Comment: In `button1_Click` you are encoding twice. What is the purpose of that and what is the real problem?

Comment: i am working with some one code. so may be that is double time encrypted.

Comment: I hope you are not using this to store sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

There is double encoding of the strings that explain the incorrect result. You are also using different text encodings when encrypting and decrypting. ASCII vs UTF8, this should be the same.

The following example provides the result I would expect:

```
        byte[] b = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test abc");
        string base64Encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
        b = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded);
        Console.WriteLine( System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(b)); 
        // "test abc"
```

As mentioned in the comments, this is not encryption, but encoding.

Comment: the results rearding ZIRT/WklSVA/V2tsU1ZB are already explained by double encoding and have nothing to do with ASCII vs. UTF8 and using UTF8 on a pure ASCII text should also not matter.